# How do we bucket aggregate only on the matched prefix on Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, analytics

I indexed some documents on Elaticsearch and one of the fields of the documents is "users" which is an array of users. Now I try to find documents per user where the user name matches some prefix. The prefix is used to filter documents. But I want the returned buckets to be also filtered by the same prefix as well. Is there anyway to do that? Below samples explain the problem.

Create an index test1:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test1/'
```

Create 9 documents for type type1 in index test1:

```
    i=1
while [ $i -lt 10 ] ; do

    curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/test1/type1/$i" -d '{
        "users" : ["ram", "hari", "balu"]
    }'
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Now run the aggregations for documents per user where user name matches the prefix "ra"

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test1/type1/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "prefix_match_aggr": {
        "filter" : { "prefix" : {"users" : "ra"}},
        "aggs" : {
            "actual_aggr" : {
                "terms": {
                    "field" : "users",
                    "size" : 0
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

The aggregation returns the below:

```
{
  "took" : 14,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 9,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "prefix_match_aggr" : {
      "doc_count" : 9,
      "actual_aggr" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [ {
          "key" : "balu",
          "doc_count" : 9
        }, {
          "key" : "hari",
          "doc_count" : 9
        }, {
          "key" : "ram",
          "doc_count" : 9
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As we can see, it returned buckets for all the users balu, hari and ram. Is there a way to only return the buckets matching the prefix "ra" i.e. the buckets for ram, rami, raman etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I got the answer. The terms aggregation has to use "include" field, So the query now will be:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test1/type1/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "prefix_match_aggr": {
        "filter" : { "prefix" : {"users" : "ra"}},
        "aggs" : {
            "actual_aggr" : {
                "terms": {
                    "field" : "users",
                    "include" : "ra.*",
                    "size" : 0
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```